# How to show two pictures in one cell in Jupyter Notebook? (matplotlib) (python)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, data-science

[image: coffee]

[image: horse]

As a beginner, can someone please help me with this? Is there any way to show both pictures in a single cell's output? My output could only display one picture. Thank you for your time and attention!

Here is my code:

```
from skimage import data
image_coffee = data.coffee()
image_horse = data.horse()
fig = plt.figure(dpi=100)
plt.imshow(image_coffee)
plt.imshow(image_horse)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [plt.subplots](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html):

```
from skimage import data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
image_coffee = data.coffee()
image_horse = data.horse()
fig,ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2,nrows=1)
ax[0].imshow(image_coffee)
ax[2].imshow(image_horse)
```

[image]